# Save image file path to Core Data

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, uiimagepickercontroller

After much research about the best way to save an image to a sqlite db in iOS, i've decided to save the filepath of the image in an entity and just reference it when it comes to displaying it as a thumbnail.

I'm using the following code to save the image taken with the camera:

```
    - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)snagPhoto editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
    [self.library saveImage:snagPhoto toAlbum:@"Snags" withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error) {

        if (error) 
        {  
            NSLog(@"error");  
        } 
    }];  

    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

All I need to do is get the filepath of 'snagPhoto'.

Comment: What kind of class is `self.library`?

Comment: It's part of the ALAssetsLibrary framework Apple introduced in iOS4

Comment: Got it. Shouldn't the call be to `writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:orientation:completionBlock:`? That will return an assetURL you can use to call up the same image later.

Comment: You're right, I've gone with the official method (the one i was using was from a tutorial)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper method to use on `ALAssetsLibrary` is `writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:metadata:completionBlock:` or `writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:orientation:completionBlock:` -- these will lead to an asset URL that you can later use with `assetForURL:resultBlock:failureBlock:` to get a reference to the image.